# List first relay mail server from header

Tags: email

The mails are stored with full headers in a text file. (The file is an INBOX from the Thunderbird mail client. File format is a [mboxrd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) variation.)

How to list the first server for each mail, that the email travels through before hitting the inbox? The "Received" line lists server that the email travels through. You read "Received" lines from bottom to top. The bottom-most line is the originator.

One option could be a custom script for text processing via `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, etc. Also searched for mail analyzer and found [E-Mail Header Analyzer (MHA)](https://github.com/cyberdefenders/email-header-analyzer), [maildir-utils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/maildir-utils) and [nmh - Message Handling System](https://www.nongnu.org/nmh/). Is it easier with one of those tools to query my file to accomplish the list of the servers that relay the email first?

Comment: I think `awk` can do both, unfolding the headers and find the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the mbox file into an approximation of its constituent messages based on the occurrence of *From* (without a colon). Then I would iterate across the set, picking out the last *Received* header for each.

```
mbox=/path/to/mbox/file

mkdir xx
(
    cd xx
    csplit -ksz -n5 "$mbox" '/^From /' '{*}'

    for m in *
    do
        awk '
            /^\r?$/ { gsub(/[\r\n[:space:]]+/, " ", received); print received; exit }
            /^[^[:space:]]/ { flag = 0 }
            /^Received:/ { received = $0; flag = 1 }
            /^[[:space:]]/ && flag { received = received " " $0 }
        ' "$m"
    done
)
rm -rf xx
```

It wouldn't be much harder to have `awk` read the original mbox file, but when I set off to create a solution I worked with a single message. Extending that solution with a shell loop seemed easier than extending the `awk`, but in hindsight it was probably only about 60:40 one way or the other.

Given that the `awk` script does process one message at a time, a utility such as [`formail`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/procmail/formail.1.en.html) (mentioned originally in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747977/list-first-relay-mail-server-from-header/748136#comment1423123_748136) as being from the [`procmail` suite](https://github.com/BuGlessRB/procmail)) can be used to iterate across the messages in an mbox format file:

```
formail < "$mbox" -s awk '....'
```

Comment: Thanks, there are several ways to accomplish this output using text processing. My question was more in a conceptual direction. If people using mail specific software to solve this task.

Comment: Also, see the [`formail` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/formail) in the `procmail` package.  It can iterate a shell command over each message in an mbox. The entire syntax becomes roughly: `formail < "$mbox" -s awk '....'`

Comment: @JimL. ah, thank you. I thought there'd be a utility command somewhere to do that sort of thing but I didn't think of looking in `procmail`

Comment: @Hölderlin I've updated the answer to incorporate a suggestion from JimL that uses `formail` from the `procmail` suite

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^Received: / {
   LASTREAD=$0
   exit
}
/^\r{0,1}$/ {
   if "" == LASTREAD {
      exit 1
   }
   print LASTREAD
   exit 0
}
END {
   if "" == LASTREAD {
      exit 1
   }
   print LASTREAD
}'
```

(not tested).

This will extract the first matching line. Whether that is the first hop is a different matter. The structure of the content may vary.

Comment: For any given message, the first "Received" line is the last hop. You also need to consider continuation lines, and that the OP seems to have implied that there multiple messages in the single text file

Comment: Fixed - but still dubious about how consistent this may be